# Finding value $ \lim_{t \to 0} \frac{t}{\sqrt{4+t} - \sqrt{4-t}}$

Tags: calculus, limits

Calculus the complete course edition eight chapter 1.2 exercise 25

> $$ \lim_{t \to 0} \frac{t}{\sqrt{4+t} - \sqrt{4-t}}$$

How do I do this?

Comment: Method #2: L'Hospital Method #3: Use [symmetric derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_derivative)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint:**
$$\dfrac{t}{\sqrt{4+t}-\sqrt{4-t}}\times\dfrac{\sqrt{4+t}+\sqrt{4-t}}{\sqrt{4+t}+\sqrt{4-t}}$$

Comment: You may want: $$\dfrac{t}{\sqrt{4+t}-\sqrt{4-t}}\times\dfrac{\sqrt{4+t}\color{red}{+}\sqrt{4-t}}{\sqrt{4+t}\color{red}{+}\sqrt{4-t}}$$

Comment: But that would just end up as 0*sqrt(4)-0*sqrt(4)=0?

Comment: @StackTD Thanks!

Comment: denominator is 4+t - (4-t) = 2t

Answer (score 1):

You may use the [l'Hopital's rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule), as follows:

$$\begin{align}\lim_{t\rightarrow0}\frac{t}{\sqrt{4+t}-\sqrt{4-t}}&=\lim_{t\rightarrow0}\frac{1}{\frac{1}{2\sqrt{4+t}}+\frac{1}{2\sqrt{4-t}}}\\
&=\lim_{t\rightarrow0}\frac{2\sqrt{(4+t)(4-t)}}{\sqrt{4+t}+\sqrt{4-t}}\\
&=\frac{2\sqrt{16}}{\sqrt4+\sqrt4}\\
&=2
\end{align}$$
So the answer is $2$.

Comment: We are not allowed to use that rule but thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $\frac{t}{\sqrt{4+t}-\sqrt{4-t}}=\frac{t(\sqrt{4+t}+\sqrt{4-t})}{2t}$

Comment: But if t is zero then it doesn't work. Please explain

Comment: @JavaProgrammer  Cancel the factor of $t$ from the numerator and denominator, then take the limit.

Answer (score 0):

Let $t=4\cos2u, t\to0\implies u\to\frac\pi4$

$$\lim_{t\to0}\dfrac t{\sqrt{4+t}-\sqrt{4-t}}=\lim_{u\to\frac\pi4}\dfrac{4(\cos^2u-\sin^2u)}{2\sqrt2(\cos u-\sin u)}=\sqrt2\lim_{u\to\frac\pi4}(\cos u+\sin u)=?$$ as $u\to\frac\pi4,\cos u\to\sin u\implies\cos u-\sin u\ne0$